# IDL D format -- 26/60 is not 26.d/60.d?

Tags: format, idl-programming-language

I am trying to write something like

ep = 23 + (26/60)

and this will give me ep=23; however, if I change either of the 26 or 60 to 26. or 26.d, ep=23.43 which is what I want.

I am just curious about why is it like this? I try some searching, but the question is difficult to express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result type of an operation is given by the types of the arguments. So above, in `23/60`, the result should be `0` using integer division. But, if one of `23` or `60` is a float (specified by making them `23.` or `60.`, respectively), then the operation will be done as float division. Furthermore, setting one of them as a double makes the operation be done in double precision.